# C# core not able to delete message from sqs

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

i am using .net core with aws sdk ,
am able to read  message but after that its not getting deleted ,
Note - Default Visibility Timeout is set to 1 minute and operation getting completed with in sec but still not getting deleted .
have look on code -

```
        string qurl = "xxxxxx";
            Task<ReceiveMessageResponse> receiveMessageResponse;
            using (var sqs = new AmazonSQSClient("xxxx", "xxxxx", xxxxx))
            {
                const int maxMessages = 1;  // 1-10

                //Receiving a message
                var receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest
                {
                    // Get URL from Configuration
                    QueueUrl = qurl,
                    // The maximum number of messages to return. 
                    // Fewer messages might be returned. 
                    MaxNumberOfMessages = maxMessages,
                    // A list of attributes that need to be returned with message.
                    AttributeNames = new List<string> { "All" },
                    // Enable long polling. 
                    // Time to wait for message to arrive on queue.
                };
                receiveMessageResponse = sqs.ReceiveMessageAsync(receiveMessageRequest);


                if (receiveMessageResponse.Result.Messages != null)
                {
                    foreach (var message in receiveMessageResponse.Result.Messages)
                    {

                        Class1 obj = new Class1();
                       string finalname= obj.fnprocess(message.Body);
                        Console.WriteLine(finalname);
                        var res = message.ReceiptHandle;

                        Task<DeleteMessageResponse> DeleteMessageResponse;
                        DeleteMessageRequest deleteMessageRequest = new DeleteMessageRequest()
                        {
                            QueueUrl = qurl,
                            ReceiptHandle = res
                        };

                        DeleteMessageResponse = sqs.DeleteMessageAsync(deleteMessageRequest);



                    }

                }
            }
```

response of request as follow [image]

any suggestion what i am doing wrong .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi actually problem was with key , 
changed code to

```
var result = sqs.DeleteMessageAsync(deleteMessageRequest).Result;
```

for catch the error , now its working .

Comment: sorry, downvoting your answer. don't block async code. use await: `var result = await sqs.DeleteMessageAsync(deleteMessageRequest)`